# Different style on the Printed version of the HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm using HTML to create a simple Web Application. That would create a form and would let the users get the form filled and set up by the Computer System by getting just the required information in a simple UI form.

Now the problem I'm having is the layout of the Form is different in both cases. In the main page, I'm having **2** elements that are lying over the entire page having a background-image. But the problem is that in the printed version, they're not the same.

Images are either not showing on the page, or are...little bit messy. Have a look,

Correct markup rendering.

[image]

Printed version in the Google,

[image]

You can see that the 1/2 image is now rendered incorrectly. And the second image, BE & OE is not longer available.

There is one other issue with the page too.

[image]

The printed version is

[image]

You can see the difference in the Header where in the real document it is Black background Header, in the Print version it is something else. Whose code I never even thought of.

These are the problems I'm having. Here is the CSS code for these

```
/* the 1/2 image */

.footer-image {
    background-image: url('../Images/snap 2.png');
    opacity: .8;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-size: cover;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

/* the BE & OE image */

.page-image {
    margin-top: 157px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-image: url('../Images/Slide1.png');
    opacity: .25;
    display: block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The code for the header is as

```
.header-sect h4 {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    max-width: 450px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 1.45em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS `@media` types?

Comment: @Krumia, exactly I have tried those,